# pip install matplotlib gives error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I use Mac OSX Sierra, and am trying to install `matplotlib` in `python 3.7`, and therefore use

```
pip3.7 install matplotlib
```

But that gives me an error

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_macosx.m -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.7/src/_macosx.o
  In file included from src/_macosx.m:1:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:6:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:7:15: error: expected ';' after @class
  @class NSArray<ObjectType>;
                ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:7:16: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @class NSArray<ObjectType>;
                 ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:25: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
                          ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:37: error: expected identifier or '('
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
                                      ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:36:13: error: expected ')'
  - (nullable ObjectType)nextObject;
              ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:36:3: note: to match this '('
  - (nullable ObjectType)nextObject;
    ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:25: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                          ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'NSEnumerator'
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
  ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:34:12: note: previous definition is here
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
             ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:37: error: method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                                      ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:40:38: error: expected a type
  @interface NSEnumerator<ObjectType> (NSExtendedEnumerator)
                                       ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:1: error: expected selector for Objective-C method
  @property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
  ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSEnumerator.h:42:36: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @property (readonly, copy) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
                                     ^
  In file included from src/_macosx.m:1:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
  In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:16:32: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>
                                 ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:16:44: error: expected identifier or '('
  @interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>
                                             ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:19:4: error: expected a type
  - (ObjectType)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
     ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:21:40: error: expected ')'
  - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const ObjectType [])objects count:(NSUInteger)cnt NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
                                         ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:21:33: note: to match this '('
  - (instancetype)initWithObjects:(const ObjectType [])objects count:(NSUInteger)cnt NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
                                  ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:26:20: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ObjectType'
  @interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray)
                     ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:26:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'NSArray'
  @interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray)
  ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:16:12: note: previous definition is here
  @interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>
             ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:26:32: error: method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'
  @interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray)
                                 ^
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:26:33: error: expected a type
  @interface NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray)
                                  ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for matplotlib
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

Comment: That's really funny, especially since the errors do not seem to directly come from matplotlib. Did you try to compile some simple C code?

Comment: Is this still a problem now that a wheel for macosx has been uploaded to pypi?